# Delayed Switching Between USB Peripherals

Tags: usb, switches, 555

I have two USB sensor pads that cannot be connected simultaneously to the computer. Currently I am using a USB hub with individual on/off switches for each port. To change pads the user MUST turn off one pad and wait for the computer to recognize the device has been removed, before turning on the second pad. Users can confuse the software (not my code, commercial software), if they switch one on before turning the other off or if they do not wait between switching.
To prevent this issue, I would like to present the users with a single momentary button. The connection would be Pad1 and Pad2 connected via USB to switch box. Switch box connected to single USB port on computer. The switch will a standard arcade style reed switch.

- Pad1 on. LED indicator on switch box confirms this.
- User pushes momentary button.
- Pad1 USB power is turned off and Pad1 LED on switch box turns off.
- Circuit waits 3 seconds.
- Pad2 USB power is turned on and Pad2 LED on switch box lights.

The same process to switch back, 1 button press = pad2 off and pad1 on.
I don't believe I need to switch the USB data, only power?
I have a bucket of caps/resisters and some 555's on hand. Can I create a simple circuit that will operate off the USB source that can achieve what I am after?

Comment: I'd still recommend fixing software problems in software – depending on the OS, you might be able to intercept registration of a new USB device (on linux: udev rules, on windows probably through an intermediate driver), and simply not make it available to applications until your program says its OK.

Comment: If you go for your hardware solution: This sounds like more work than it's worth if done with a 555. A USB bus switch (they exist for exactly USB switching reasons) with a minimal microcontroller firmware might work better, and be offering you features like the microcontroller actually waiting for a command from the PC that it's ready to accept a new device.

Comment: Completely agree on the software first scenario. The problem there is the program does not see the deviceid. it only recognizes it as a proprietary sensor. Unfortunately my usage require two of the same sensors in different locations, switching back and forth depending on need. It would require an adjustment in the code to allow the software to do the switching.

Comment: I am currently using a bus switch but it allows two devices to be connected simultaneously. I am trying to simplify for the end users, cause we know how they are.

Comment: The answer to your question as stated is "Yes". Your implied question - "Can someone here help me design this thing?" is too broad. You need to do some research and come back with more specific focussed questions.